# How to read library errors c++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I was compiling a c++ project to simulate a language changing over time from a small subset of introduced words, it was working fine until it wouldn't compile and outputed library error garblygoook. Normally this wouldn't be an issue I can debug normal errors on my own, but the error message is very unreadable(at least to a beginner) it appears to be some werid library error, perhaps connected to the standard algorithm library. I need some help to decode it and understand what is going wrong. Any other tips and tricks for reading these werid messages in the future would be much appreciated. Note: I'm using mingw on windows, with c++17.

[error message from compiler](https://github.com/crabster15/LangEvolve/blob/main/error.txt)

code I believe may be causing the issue(from wordmod.cpp):

```
std::vector<int> WordMod::CreateChangedMask(std::string Word){
std::vector<int> changedCharsMask;
for( int currCharPos = 0; currCharPos < Word.length()-1; currCharPos++){
    int maskNum = rand() % 100 + 1;
    if(std::find(VowelChars.begin(), VowelChars.end(), Word[currCharPos]) != VowelChars.end()){
        changedCharsMask.push_back(0);
    }
    else if (maskNum <= PERCENT_CHANGE){
        changedCharsMask.push_back(1);
    }
    else{
        changedCharsMask.push_back(0);
    }

}
```

[full github code](https://github.com/crabster15/LangEvolve)

Comment: The error messages should be included as text in the question, not a link. Someone else with the same problem won't find your question if they do a search for the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is on line 70 in the wordMod.cpp file. specifically this function:

```cpp
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Word>> WordMod::DeleteRepeats(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Word>> wordlist){
    for(int currword = 0; currword < wordlist.size(); currword++){
        wordlist.erase(std::remove(wordlist.begin(), wordlist.end(), wordlist[currword]->get_word()), wordlist.end());
    }
    return wordlist;
}
```

in the `std::remove` call i assume your intention is to remove every element where the word is the same as the word gotten from `wordlist[currword]->get_word()`. the standart library does this by going through each element between `wordlist.begin()` and `wordlist.end()` and checking if any of them are equal to `wordlist[currword]->get_word()`.

but `wordlist` is a not a vector of `std::string` objects (which i assume is what `wordlist[currword]->get_word()` returns), it is a vector of `std::shared_ptr<Word>` meaning the standard library tries to check if the `std::shared_ptr<Word>` is equal to a `std::string`. and the library does not know how to check for that equality.

the easy fix would be to change the function to:

```cpp
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Word>> WordMod::DeleteRepeats(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Word>> wordlist){
    for(int currword = 0; currword < wordlist.size(); currword++){
        wordlist.erase(std::remove_if(wordlist.begin(), wordlist.end(), [&](std::shared_ptr<Word> w){
            return wordlist[currword]->get_word() == w->get_word();
        }), wordlist.end());
    }
    return wordlist;
}
```

edit:

i have also noticed that this function will actually just delete every element in the vector as you are also removing the elemnt you are comparing against. the second version of this function would look like this:

```cpp
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Word>> WordMod::DeleteRepeats(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Word>> wordlist){
    for(int currword = 0; currword < wordlist.size(); currword++){
        if(currword != wordlist.size()-1){
            wordlist.erase(std::remove_if(wordlist.begin()+currword+1, wordlist.end(), [&](std::shared_ptr<Word> w){
                return wordlist[currword]->get_word() == w->get_word();
            }), wordlist.end());
        }
    }
    return wordlist;
}
```

this version of the function will only remove elements AFTER the one you are comparing to

edit2:

for clarity i got thet from the error by checking the first error of them all:

```
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algobase.h:71,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\char_traits.h:39,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\string:40,
                 from wordMod.hpp:6,
                 from wordMod.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\predefined_ops.h: In instantiation of 'bool __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_equals_val<_Value>::operator()(_Iterator) [with _Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::shared_ptr<Word>*, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Word> > >; _Value = const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]':      
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:869:13:   required from '_ForwardIterator std::__remove_if(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, _Predicate) [with _ForwardIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::shared_ptr<Word>*, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Word> > >; _Predicate = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_equals_val<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >]'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:906:30:   required from '_FIter std::remove(_FIter, _FIter, const _Tp&) [with _FIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::shared_ptr<Word>*, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Word> > >; _Tp = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]'
wordMod.cpp:70:100:   required from here
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\predefined_ops.h:241:17: error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'std::shared_ptr<Word>' and 'const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>')
  241 |  { return *__it == _M_value; }
      |
```

the line `wordMod.cpp:70:100:   required from here` told me that the problem was in the `wordMod.cpp` file on line `70` and the line

```
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:906:30:   required from '_FIter std::remove(_FIter, _FIter, const _Tp&) [with _FIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::shared_ptr<Word>*, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Word> > >; _Tp = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]'
```

told me that the problem was somehow in the `std::remove` call made on that line.

c++ compilers have a tendency to spit out long and wierd and complicated errors, but the way to attack them is to just take a look at the very first error, fix that one and then a lot of the time when that one gets fixed the other ones get fixed as well. take them one at a time

Comment: Thanks for the explaination, however your code doesn't seem to be returning the object to be deleted. I keep getting a 'std::logic_error' at runtime and it appears to be returning a null which can't be removed. At least I think that is what is happening.

Comment: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid

Comment: i find it wierd that my code would do that, i think that problem is somewhere else in the code, for example the file `meaninghandler.cpp` has a function called `GetRandomMeaning()` which could throw this error if the `meaninglist` vector is empty. i would advise using a good debugger that integrates with your IDE to find out where that error is. the debugger will normally break when that error is thrown and then you can look at the call stack for where the error originated in your code

Comment: I figured it out it was a segmentation fault somewhere else in the program, I really need to look up and learn more about lambas, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I usually start from the top and looking for my files listed (usally looking for `*.cpp`).

This directs to this line:

```
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:906:30:   required from '_FIter std::remove(_FIter, _FIter, const _Tp&) [with _FIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::shared_ptr<Word>*, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Word> > >; _Tp = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]'
wordMod.cpp:70:100:   required from here
```

So lets take a look at `wordMod.cpp:70`:

```cpp
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Word>> WordMod::DeleteRepeats(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Word>> wordlist){
    for(int currword = 0; currword < wordlist.size(); currword++){
        wordlist.erase(std::remove(wordlist.begin(), wordlist.end(), wordlist[currword]->get_word()), wordlist.end()); // this line is 70
    }
    return wordlist;
}
```

A quick glimpse of this code may look ok, so see what next error message says:

```
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\predefined_ops.h:241:17: error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'std::shared_ptr<Word>' and 'const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>')
  241 |  { return *__it == _M_value; }
```

So your code requires `operator==` between `std::shared_ptr<Word>` and `const std::string` what is obviously wrong.

In last step take a look on details what you are trying to do:

- you are removing elements of vector
- which contains `shared_ptr` (left argument of `operator==`)
- and you are searching for value which type is `std::string`, since this is what `get_word()` returns (right argument of `operator==`)

So now it should be obvious what is wrong.